# Remove decimal ciphers when value is an integer

Tags: javascript, numbers

In my web-app I'm working with simple mathematical calculations using javascript and I have to show results in a page.

The result can be a decimal value or an integer, so at the moment i'm using the `toFixed` method to limit decimal ciphers that may be present.

Obviously, using `toFixed(2)` I always get something like `1.00` even if the value is an integer. So I'd like to find a way to avoid decimal ciphers when the value is not a float.
Is there any method or util function to achieve this?

Comment: What about doing a string replace of ".00" to ""?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string... is that what you want?  JavaScript math should already handle it for you... `1 + 1.00` vs `1 + 1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removes ".00"

```
yourNumber.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/,"");
```

Replaces trailing zeros with nothing, and removes decimal point it there are no decimals.

```
yourNumber.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Number.round](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Number#Number%3around) from mootools (note I quickly adapted it to a util I may of missed something):

```
var round = function (num, precision){
    precision = Math.pow(10, precision || 0).toFixed(precision < 0 ? -precision : 0);
    return Math.round(num * precision) / precision;
}
```

Some tests:

```
round(5, 2) // => 5
round(5.9, 2) // => 5.9
round(5.005, 2) // => 5.01
round(5.132, 2) // => 5.13
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript almost already handles it for you.  You can use `toFixed` and then cast it back to a number (since `toFixed` returns a string):

```
var a = 1, b = 1.1111111;
console.log(+(a + b).toFixed(2)); // 2.11

var a = 1, b = 1;
console.log(+(a + b).toFixed(2)); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to previously check if my result is an integer value or not by checking:

```
result % 1 === 0
```

Then if this condition is true i can avoid to use `toFixed` on my result.